# pivot long by group in SAS

Tags: sas, pivot, transform, transpose

I have a table in the following structure:

| month | filter1 | filter2 | account | payment | users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 0 | 4535 | 564 | 5000 |
| Jan | 1 | 1 | 7387 | 787 | 8000 |
| Feb | 1 | 0 | 567 | 5 | 600 |

In SAS I am looking to convert it into the following format:

| month | filter1 | filter2 | value | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 0 | account | 4535 |
| Jan | 1 | 0 | payment | 564 |
| Jan | 1 | 0 | users | 5000 |
| Jan | 1 | 1 | account | 7387 |

I am looking at proc transpose but I do not have same prefixes in the values, and I will need to confirm amounts in another column. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

PROC TRANSPOSE will handle your example:

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(rename=(col1=amount)) name=value ;
  by month filter1 filter2 NOTSORTED ;
  var account payment users ;
run;
```

In this example since you want to transpose all of the numeric variables you can just skip the VAR statement.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a data step transpose, but this requires all your variables to be the same type or stored as a character field so I can see this being problematic as well. You may want to store the type to make your life easier on later.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array _vars(*) account payment users;
  do i=1 to dim(_vars);
     value = vname (_vars(i));
     amount = _vars(i);
     output;
  end;
*drop account payment users;
run;
```

UCLA has good tutorials on the [proc transpose option](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-wide-to-long-using-proc-transpose/)
and the
[data step option](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-wide-to-long-using-a-data-step/):